# Manage disk space with Final Cut X

Tags: backup, disk-space, final-cut-pro

My hard drive is full and I have a finished project on it that may require some small modification.

What is the good way to manage Final Cut X data? I have a 50Gb Final Cut file in my Video folder and don't know how to process...

Answer (score 1):

The [Final Cut Library Manager](http://www.arcticwhiteness.com/finalcutlibrarymanager/) is a wonderful app that lets you selectively remove optimised and proxy media as well as render files, freeing space. These can be recreated if necessary from the original media and timeline.

> [image]

The original media is still required if you wish to edit the footage in the future.

Comment: This look promising! But do I have to move my local library to my NAS with the finder?